# Checkbox List Disable / Enable Function

Tags: list, button, checkbox

So basically I have a 5 checkboxes where if the user selects any of the two boxes the rest will be disabled so that they can't pick anymore but enable those boxes if any of the two boxes are deselected.

This will be inside a form.

Thanks!

So I tried one of the method below with the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll">??
<input type="checkbox" name="checkOUT" id="checkOUT">AA
<input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="book1">book1
<input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="book2">book2
<input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="book3">book3
<input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="book4">book4
<input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="book5">book5</table>

<script>
$(function () {
$("#checkAll" && "#checkOUT").click(function () {
    if ($("#checkAll" && "#checkOUT").is(':checked')) {
        $(".book").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".book").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I can't seem to get it so when both checkboxes are selected then disable.

Comment: how does combo box work with checkboxes?

Comment: 2 combo box with 5 select items in it and validate whether two different items are selected. asking this for HTML ?

Comment: I see what you mean. That's true it would be easier.

Comment: if $("#checkAll").is(':checked') & $("#checkAll").is(':checked')

Comment: it works but if I select checkOUT first then checktAll, it doesn't disable the other boxes

Answer (score 0):

In the "CheckedChanged" event of an active CheckBox, enable the other CheckBox.

```
Private Sub chkbx_one_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkbx_one.CheckedChanged
  If DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
    chkbx_two.Enabled = True
  End If
End Sub
```